# How to use the .monospaced system font design

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am attempting to use a system font and apply the monospaced design, without luck. I can successfully make the text monospaced using the custom font function and passing in `Courier` and a size, but this is not idea because then the font size is fixed.

[image]

```swift
VStack {
    Text("lmlmlmlm 12345678")
    Text("lmlmlmlm 12345678")
    .font(Font.system(.body, design: .monospaced))
    Text("lmlmlmlm 12345678")
    .font(Font.custom("Courier", size: 18))
}
```

How do I get the system font to work with the `.monospaced` design? I think it might be a bug with `.monospaced`, because the `.serif` option does modify the text as expected.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

It seems `.monospaced` font only applies when given a fixed size:

```
Text("monospaced")
  .font(.system(size: 14, design: .monospaced))
```

This won't work given a dynamic text style such as `body`. But as you've also mentioned it works fine for other fonts so this is probably a bug in Xcode 11.0 beta and hopefully will be fixed in next releases.

---

#### Update:

This issue was fixed with **Xcode 11 beta 3**. The following code works now:

```
Text("monospaced")
    .font(.system(.body, design: .monospaced))
```

Comment: Saw that too and submitted a bug report to Apple using the Feedback Assistant - FB6146888

Answer (score 9):

In case you want to make only digits monospaced, you might try using something like this:

```
Text("0123456789")
    .font(Font.system(.body, design: .monospaced).monospacedDigit())
```

This does not circumvent the obvious bug of Xcode 11.0 beta, however. Letters are still not rendered monospaced.

Comment: If you want only the digits monospaced, you sould set the 'design' argument to '.default'. Cheers.